# Someone will help me?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

how to change design in this bed sheet?
And it should look real.

Does anyone have a solution?[image]

Comment: If it was one color or the print was waaaay less intricate, it would be doable, but you'd have to basically repaint the shadows. Because of this print, the shadows aren't really salvageable, aside from that one white section in the front. Or it would also help if the bed cover wasn't so droopy. Because then it would be simpler to fake the shadows. I would personally say no to this.

Comment: This isn't a job for Photoshop, it's a job for dedicated mockup software.

Comment: Or 3D model with photorealistic render.

Comment: Ultimately, you can buy that house and take proper photos of each sheet. Joking obviously, but the point is – not everything can be done in Photoshop. Find a different way.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is common - a good photo exists but the design pattern should be changed to a new image file without losing the plausibility. That means right position, right bumps, twists and bendings, right highlights and shadows, right perspective and right general color which matches with the apparent light in the photo.

As already said in comments, bedding and bed linen mockups are created for this - an otherwise perfect playground composition has been prepared, add only your own design (and the room, if the mockup hasn't one). Photoshop's layer and object functionality do the rest (guided by complex predefined masks, filterings and maps)

Unfortunately mockups do not adapt to your viewing angle, light  nor how your fabric should be bent & folded. Purchased mockups have invariably their own geometry which is the basement of the mockup.

In theory and also in practice you can deform your own design to fit the photo. It means careful warping and manual inserting the lights and shadows. But that's a demanding task, well beyond the skills of a beginner. It's much easier, if one omits small wrinkles and foldings. We'll try it later.

To be able to try easily several different fabric designs you must know well how to warp, adjust lights & colors and how to do them with masked adjustment layers, layer styles and smart objects. You would essentially create a new mockup.

There's another suggestion "take a new photo". That's not a bad joke, not even if your new design or several of them are only graphic software files. Taking a new photo with uniform white or other single color unpatterned fabric parts lets you control how the bends and bumps are (of course they should be simple) and gives to you lights and shadows for easy reuse with layer blending modes. You must only warp your design image to fit.

This is what you can get easily by warping a new design image onto your photo.

[image]

The job was done in Afinity Photo because its Warping Mesh is incredibly responsive and controllable. Illustrator's Envelope Distort with mesh is nearly the same.

The "New design" is of course here a quite random pattern (=rectangular and lasso selections are filled with colors, a grainy texture filtering). The "Design" was originally a square. The corners were dragged at first to their places, then the mesh got more points which were dragged to their places. Here's a screenshot after dragging the corners:

[image]

And here's more points inserted. The layer is temporarily made transparent to see the original edges better:

[image]

There's are layer "Blanket Shading" with blending mode Hard Light. It has only grey. Here's a quite early phase of the blanket shading layer. It has still blending mode=normal. The blanket area is selected and filled with 50% grey, some white is sprayed with a smooth brush:

[image]

The result is like a thin blanket. To get some apparent thickness the edges must be made complex. I skipped it. Just in this case careful shading could do the job, because there's no lines which need foldings. The next image shows how shading can create apparent thickness. It's actually a reduced opacity black inner glow effect (rasterized and wiped off elsewhere)

[image]

As said earlier, one could get very plausible shading by taking a photo of single color bedding. If you haven't it you must paint the shading gradually more complex and insert new bumps also to warping. In illustrator one can insert more details to the same envelope distortion mesh which is an advantage. In Affinity Photo the mesh is applied and deleted as soon as one exits from the warping. To be able to get back to an older version one must make layer copies or savings.

There's no theoretical obstacles in front of a fully realistic result. In practice to get there one must have between his ears something that a painting master has. I haven't it, so I do not try to insert fine wrinkles manually. If one had a shading image which is a photo of a real single color bedding, he could create fake wrinkles with Displacement Map (=a common effect in Photoshop and many other raster image editors).

I guess this older case is interesting: [Creating 3d mock-up texture](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119361/creating-3d-mock-up-texture)

As already suggested 3D modelling also could be used. Photorealistic rendering would make realistic results if one had a realistic surface model. Advanced 3D modelling software with physics really could simulate how a blanket would settle on the bed. All bends and wrinkles would appear automatically once one had programmed how the blanket is built and thrown on the bed. But getting the needed knowledge can take years. My skills in that area are near zero, so that subject is skipped.

In 3D program one could also make bumps, bends and wrinkles manually, so a realistic result is possible also without physics modelling. The major challenge would be to create the surface model in a way that takes easily the design image in one or a couple of pieces.

3D work should contain at least the whole bed + bedding, preferably also the room if one wants a possibility to change the view and light. Making the blanket only in 3D isn't especially useful, because it should fit to a given photo and without other 3D parts it has no other use.

**For information only**: The next image is an attempt to bend a 3D square to a surface which resembles the visible part of the blanket. The job is essentially the same as warping the new design image except it must be done in 3D. A control mesh is inserted and its nodes are moved:

[image]

Placing the design image onto the surface is a three click operation:

[image]

This is a CAD program which can make only plastic-like renderings which is typical to CAD programs. The surface is very simple, it has even less bends and bumps than the warped 2D version. But creating more surface complexity is easier than in 2D.

Proper 3D programs for artistic design can have even the fabric as 3D model. Photorealistic rendering isn't possible without a proper material library except if one wants it to look made of plastics.